# Почему нельзя использовать инкрементный подход к созданию методов при множественном наследовании?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`SingingWaiter` порожден от классов `Waiter` и `Singer`, которые порождены от класса `Worker`(вот такой ромбик получается).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написанное в книге на этих фото мне кажется чем-то очень нелогичным(бредом короче), поэтому я решил написать тестовый код и проверить все сам:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    class a
    {
    public:
        void show() {std::cout<<"i am an A!\n";}
    };

    class b : virtual public a
    {
    public:
        void show() {a::show(); std::cout<<"i am an B!\n";}
    };

    class c : virtual public a
    {
    public:
        void show() {a::show(); std::cout<<"i am an C!\n";}
    };

    class d : public b, public c
    {
     public:
        void show() {b::show(); std::cout<<"i am an C!\n";}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Если утверждения в книге верны, то класс `d` не должен давать возможности скомпилироваться программе, ведь в нем вызывается только метод `b::show()`, а должно вызываться два метода - `b::show()` и `c::show()`.  НО, программа компилируется на разных компиляторах(clang, g++). Можете [сами проверить](https://rextester.com/LROWJ63033). Что я неправильно понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно поняли слово "сбой".

Речь не о проблеме компиляции, а том что логика программы будет неправильная. Два раза вызывается метод из базового класса.

В этом примере это печать на экран два раза, но представьте, что это снятие денег со счета, а не печать.